# Can't setup php mongo driver on mac os MAMP PRO

Tags: php, macos, mongodb, mamp-pro

I have MAMP PRO php 5.6.2 and MongoDB 2.6.7

I do anything what was write here http://lukepeters.me/blog/setting-up-mongodb-with-php-and-mamp, but no result. I have run `sudo pecl install mongo`, I have `mongo.so` in `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/`, but again no result.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, there was a problem with php version, you need just to change php version to `5.5.18`